# Apache NiFi tailfile processor doesn't work well with large log files

Tags: apache-nifi, data-ingestion

I'm using Apache NiFi in order to ingest my application live log (a single log file) and publish it to Apache Kafka. 
The mentioned application generates a large number of logs (50GB per day approximately). I needed the ingestion to be near-live, so I used the tailfile processor. Ths issue is that the thread reading the file get stuck and for like hours is just active doing nothing(well not nothing, but not generating flowfiles). then all of a sudden a big xGB flow file is generated, so not very near-live ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: I think this behavior only for the first log scanning when it large. The sequential processor executions must response fast..

Comment: thank you for your response, well I thought the same thing at first but after the first flowfile (approx 8gb data) another thread freeze came along for several hours. I don't know it seems it can't keep up with the log insertion speed.